# Drawing in C# winform is fairly slow

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm creating a custom DataGridView, in which the CheckBox Shows a border when MouseHover is raised.

Here is what I've done so far.

```
    void checkBox_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //showBorder defines whether the border is drawn.
        this.showBorder = false;
        this.DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);
    }

    void CheckBoxMouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.showBorder = true;
        this.CheckBox.BringToFront();
        this.DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);
    }

    protected override void Paint(...........)
    {
        ..........
        if (showBorder)
        {
            GraphicsPath border=new GraphicsPath();
            border.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(checkBoxPosition.X-1,checkBoxPosition.Y-1,checkBoxSize.Width+1,checkBoxSize.Height+1));
            graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(borderColor,1),border);
        }
    }
```

But is comes so slow that I have to wait for about half a second to see do border show.
Anyway, MouseLeave works fine.
So how can I improve the performance here?

In addition, how can I customize the checkbox? for example, the background color, etc.

Comment: Are you familar with Double Buffering? http://www.bobpowell.net/doublebuffer.htm

Comment: I tried automatic Double Buffering, and it made no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using MouseHover event for the Mouse going over the control. Try MouseEnter instead. MouseHover is triggered after the mouse stays over the control for a little bit of time. MouseEnter is instant